# Smothe fadeIn() animation

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein

I got an issue with my fadeIn animation which wont work properly. Instead it appears instantly without any animation at all?

```
function createABRN(url) {

    formSerial2 = $('#baseForm').serialize();
    $("input[name='ipreis']").val($selPositionVals[1]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formSerial2,
        success: function (msg) {

            $(".alert").html(msg);
            $(".alert").append($($delBillLink));
            createPositions();

            $('input[name="aufbest"]').hide();
            $('input[name="iweiter"]').hide();

            $('.position').fadeIn(); //<-- no animation, just jumps in?                     
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that content isn't being shown by something else? Also, accept some answers to your questions!

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I would try this:

`$('.position').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: I know that but maybe 400ms is still too fast for him. That is why I said this would be the first thing I'd try.

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn needs a speed set, like fadeIn("slow");

EDIT:

As the commenter says, fadeIn should default to 400ms, right between slow(600ms) and fast(200ms).

Maybe you should try running the fadeIn in the ajax complete handler instead, so it fires when the ajax post is completed and the elemtent exists.

To be sure it is hidden, you could try running hide() on the element at the same time as it's inserted with ajax.

```
$('.position').hide();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formSerial2,
        success: function(msg){

          $(".alert").html(msg);
          $(".alert").append($($delBillLink));
          createPositions();

          $('input[name="aufbest"]').hide();
          $('input[name="iweiter"]').hide();
        },
        complete : function(){
          $('.position').fadeIn("slow"); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry not true: "If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used."

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answers I would suggest

```
$('.position').fadeIn('slow');
```

But you can also specifiy an integer for the number of milliseconds it should take to fade in, e.g.

```
$('.position').fadeIn(5000);
```

This would take the element 5 seconds to fade in.

Comment: thx, yes that does the trick. But also targeted the wrong element. But its solved now.

Answer (score 0):

is it initially hidden? try hiding it first:

```
$('.position').hide().fadeIn();
```